# Django: Constraint on a form field doesn't apply

Tags: django, django-forms

i'm still a beginner in django and i have problem to make something work:

In a from, i have a field which is an integer and which's value can be [0|1|2].

So i made a working stuff like this :

```
front = forms.IntegerField(label=_('quantity'), initial='', min_value=0, max_value=2)
```

This works correctly and if the fields contains another value, Django triggers an error after submitting.

As i need to use often that kind of field, i made a class of it , which is :

```
class Quarter(forms.IntegerField):
    def __init__(self, val='', min=0,max=2):
        super(forms.IntegerField, self).__init__()
        self.initial = val
        self.min_value = min
        self.max_value = max
        self.required = True
        self.error_messages = {'required': 'This field is required',
                               'max_value': 'number is too high',
                               'min_value': 'number is too low',
                               'invalid': 'Enter a valid number'}
```

And, in my from class, i call it like this :

```
rear = Quarter()
```

or

The default parameters should (i think) limit the range of values rear can receive.

But if i enter any value in the rear field, django accept them all, when it refuse it for the front one.

Shouldn't this code work, normally ?
Can you point me the mistake i do and help me to make it work correctly ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IntegerField class sets up the validation in its `__init__` method based on the values it is passed. Since you don't pass any values at all in the super call, the validation is never created.

Instead of passing nothing and then subsequently setting the values on `self`, you should simply pass them in the super call:

```
def __init__(self, min=0, max=2, *args, **kwargs):
    error_messages = {'required': 'This field is required',
                                  'max_value': 'number is too high',
                                  'min_value': 'number is too low',
                                  'invalid': 'Enter a valid number'}

   super(Quarter, self).__init__(max_value=max, min_value=min, error_messages=error_messages, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: i'm sorry but i have this :
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_value'

Comment: Sorry, you should call super on Quarter, not IntegerField. Corrected.

Comment: @Daniel: keyword arguments must be sent after list arguments, so *args must be the first argument to the method, am I wrong ? I think this causes the error mentionned by Yves.

Comment: No, the error is because he was calling super(IntegerField, self)... which means he is calling the init method of the *parent* of IntegerField - ie Field - which does not expect those arguments. The class name in super should always be the exact class you are defining, in this case Quarter.

Comment: @daniel this works perfectly. Thank you. I can't vote for your reply, my reputation is too low.

Comment: One last question : why is error_messages not more self.error_messages ?

Comment: You should at least accept the answer. And I don't understand your comment; the point is you are passing that dict up into the superclass method which sets the attribute on self.

Comment: @daniel  i mean this:  in my initial post i wrote : self.error_messages = and in your reply that became error_messages = (without the self). My question is : what's the reason of the self disapearance ? in my tests, i kept it and now it works.

Comment: You don't need reputation to accept, that's the whole point. Click the big check-mark next to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
super(forms.IntegerField, self).__init__(*args, max_value=max, min_value=min, error_messages=error_messages, **kwargs)
```

should work better

Comment: Why? Please add some explanation of what was wrong, and how this makes it better.

Comment: @spectras: sorry, the explanation is in my comment below.